# mount hard drive from mac on ubuntu server

Tags: server, partitioning, mount, backup, macosx

I have a 2011 macbook pro that's on it's last legs.  so I tried taking the hard drive out and mounting it on my ubuntu server, so I could copy the contents of the hard drive to my ubuntu server.  the problem I'm having is that the file type doesn't seem to be specified for the partition (/dev/sd32), and when I try to copy it using the same file format that the other partition on the drive has "vfat" I get the errors below.  I've also tried using hfsplus but get same error message.  does anyone have a suggestion how to solve the mounting issue when it doesn't show the file type?  or does anyone have an alternative suggestion for backing up the hard drive from a mac?  I've got a new frame work laptop that I'm going to run ubuntu desktop on and transfer the files to from the old mac.

code tried:

```
sudo mount -t hfsplus /dev/sde2 /mnt/copy_hdd_data
mount: /mnt/copy_hdd_data: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sde2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.



sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sde2 /mnt/copy_hdd_data
mount: /mnt/copy_hdd_data: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sde2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.


sudo mount /dev/sde2 /mnt/copy_hdd_data
mount: /mnt/copy_hdd_data: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sde2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

info about file systems attached:

```
sudo blkid
/dev/nvme0n1: LABEL="nvme0n1partition" UUID="26a5ef2a-c59e-4ecc-91c4-49ee9f7xxxxx" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/nvme1n1p1: UUID="07B8-44EA" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="e5f492ef-dcad-4d3c-b2ae-9f5xxxxx"
/dev/nvme1n1p2: UUID="1c15c52e-c08a-488c-bc55-2c2998a3273a" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="19ae5126-ad50-419a-8128-01fxxxx"
/dev/sda1: UUID="bcfa2097-e5c8-4b71-b326-a15527cb1970" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="d110c6f4-08a9-334f-8bd8-xxxx"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="2cf88dbb-d018-43ac-ba8d-61a2de6e2170" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="c3d03051-d09b-9b4c-89c8-xxxxx"
/dev/sdc1: UUID="6a184ac7-7392-425b-aafa-2bb7607cd5f9" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="dac74467-97fb-7e41-bda1-59xxxxx"
/dev/sdd1: LABEL="sdapartition" UUID="34d95c8f-d778-41e1-92f7-09db340ccdc4" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="9c6486c3-1d29-478e-984d-ed3xxxxxx"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sde1: LABEL="EFI" UUID="67E3-17ED" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="efeb66a0-ddf2-4ff8-b497-0xxxxx"
/dev/nvme1n1: PTUUID="ca11a68d-58fb-4c20-a3bd-d7d7dc571dbe" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/sde2: PARTUUID="dbfb7cdd-c070-4a7b-924c-21acxxxxx"
```

Comment: Are you sure the device is formatted HFS+? If you’ve updated MacOS to anything beyond 10.12 it would have been converted to [APFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_File_System). If the device *is* APFS, then you will need to use [fsapfsmount](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/fsapfsmount.1.html).

Comment: @matigo thank you for getting back to me so quickly.  I'm running macos high sierra 10.13.6.  I just tried hfsplus because it was mentioned in a post.  when I run blkid I can see and later mount one of the partitions "sde1" and when I explore it, it seems to be the operating system.  the other partition on sde2 is the one I can't seem to mount.  also when I run blkid it doesn't show a type for that partition on sde2.  will fsapfsmount solve those issues so I can mount the sde2 partition and copy my files off the hard drive?

Comment: Is the package *hfsplus* installed?

Comment: @chili555 yes the package hfsplus is installed

Comment: If you encrypted your data partition, then you may have additional hurdles to overcome. It may be simpler to access the storage device via another Mac, even if it’s inside a VM.

Comment: @matigo I tried running "sudo apt-get install libfsapfs-utils" but got "E: Unable to locate package libfsapfs-utils" even after running sudo apt-get update.  any suggestions?

Comment: @matigo also I'm on ubuntu 18.04, can libfsapfs-utils be intalled on that version of linux?

Comment: From what I can see, the library that I referenced was introduced in 20.04. It may be possible to find a version that works with 18.04, but I no longer have any 18.04-based systems to test this with.